# Git hook for whenever HEAD changes

Tags: git, githooks

My aim is to keep an (untracked) file up to date with the current HEAD commit hash, branch and some other details. I have a working git `post-checkout` hook that updates the file, but I want the hook to run whenever HEAD changes, whether that is by commit, merge or whatever else might be possible.

**What is the easiest way to ensure that my hook runs whenever HEAD changes?**

### Details

The file that I am generating is a javascript file which is part of a statically served website. We have no dependency on server side scripting, so we would like to avoid such a dependency here.

The script that should be run is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=js/git-status.js

echo "// This file is autogenerated by a post-checkout hook. Your changes here WILL be lost." > $FILE

echo "GIT_BRANCH = '$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)';" >> $FILE
echo "GIT_COMMIT_HASH = '$(git rev-parse HEAD)';" >> $FILE
echo "GIT_COMMIT_TIME = '$(git log -1 -s --format=%ci HEAD)';"  >> $FILE

echo "Updated $FILE"
```

While there may be another approach I could take, I would still like an answer to the original question.

Comment: There are `post-commit` and `post-merge` hooks you can use as well, but what are you trying accomplish with this file that you can't get by just calling `git status` or `git log`?

Comment: is there any reason you cannot track the head from the .git directory? (eg: `cat .git/$(sed 's/.*\s\+//' .git/HEAD)`)

Comment: The script formats the values that I want as JavaScript variable assignments for inclusion in a staticly served site. An acceptable answer would be a list of all hooks that I need to include to cover all (or as many as possible) possibilities.

Comment: What do you have in your post-checkout?

Comment: There is no hook to do what you want that i am aware of.  Normally people use a bare repository for this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it may not be possible (though please prove me wrong), so I have settled with this good-enough approach: I trigger the script from a number of hooks, which means that it will be run most of the time.

These are the hooks that I am using:

- post-checkout
- post-commit
- post-merge
- post-rebase